# What is the cause of Error: Could not find or load main class when running spark-shell

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I installed spark 2.3.3 on Windows 8.1. I have set up env variables: JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME and added them to path. When I try to run spark-shell I get an error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class .lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

I run commandline with administrator privilleges.
How can I get more details about the error to solve it?

Comment: Have you downloaded winutils.exe?

Comment: Yes, they are in the directory where HADOOP_HOME is pointing

Comment: I have solved the problem. I could not find out what caused the problem, but uninstalling Java and then installing it again helped.